# How many StackOverflow/StackExchange users are still using IE8?

Tags: support

I know that IE8 is officially no longer supported on StackOverflow, but I'm now in a pity situation where my only browser with connection to internet in workspace is that browser-like tool.

I've noticed that, from today, the features that doesn't work in IE8 anymore are voting, commenting and searching for tags. Additionally, asking question always triggers captchas, which are currently almost impossible to solve.

Do you store information, what browsers are users using? Could you tell us, how many of them are still using IE8? I'm the only creature from the place forgotten by gods, or there are more unlucky fellows as I?

Comment: To be exact? 18.958 users.

Comment: Check your local laws. If your workplace forces you to use IE8, you probably can sue them for cruel and unusual punishment.

Comment: IE8? You must be using Windows XP which will (still) be .... supported by Microsoft in 7 days indeed....

Comment: A fix for this issue is [on its way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227664/140505)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the problem is, nobody forces me to use IE8. It's simply the only way to access the internet. But the choice is mine.

Comment: @Rob if you have some sources to support, it would be an answer :D:D